# Global costmap empty

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, costmap, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am developing a system that, among other things, gives navigation goals on a previously mapped (GMapping) occupancy map to a Turtlebot.

The system works fine, except for when a goal is given that is at the edge of the map, still inside the unoccupied space (grey), but within collision range of the Turtlebot. When this happens, move_base responds by spamming "Unable to get starting pose of robot, unable to create global plan" and trying to recover from this, but never managing to.

In order to avoid this case, I want to read the global 2D costmap for inflated obstacles. However, nothing is published on /move_base/global_costmap/obstacles and /move_base/global_costmap/inflated_obstacles.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76132/global-costmap-empty/) by [flauflauf](https://answers.ros.org/users/6346/flauflauf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently publish_frequency for global_costmap is set to 0.0 by default. Changing this to 5.0 solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [flauflauf](https://answers.ros.org/users/6346/flauflauf/) with karma: 26 on 2013-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1